# SQL Where clause starting with number

Tags: sql

In SQL there are queries that starts with number after where clause (where 3>= ( select ...). Most of time, I only encounter where clause having a field, but not like the one below.

How should I interpret the 3>= select(...) part? I was trying to google it, but I cannot seem to find the right keyword which will lead to the correct resource.

```
select distinct salary
from worker w1
where 3 >= 
(select count(distinct salary)
from worker w2
where 
w1.salary <= w2.salary)
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  The `WHERE` clause is just an inequality, that is all.

Comment: it translates to :" there should be 3 or more distinct salary value"

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct salary
from worker w1
where 3 >= 
(select count(distinct salary)
from worker w2
where 
w1.salary <= w2.salary)
```

In above query `3 >= (select count(distinct salary)from worker w2 where w1.salary <= w2.salary)` is ensuring that for each salary in worker table there is at best three records with higher salary; not more than that.

You can rearrange the query like below for better understanding:

```
 select distinct salary
    from worker w1
    where (select count(distinct salary)
    from worker w2
    where     w2.salary >= w1.salary)<=3
```

If your dbms supports common table expression and window ranking function then far more efficient way can be below one.

```
;with cte as 
(
   select salary,row_number()over(partition by salary order by salary) rn,DENSE_RANK()over(order by salary desc)dns_rank from employee
)
select salary from cte where rn=1 and dns_rank <=3
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is flip your logic from

```
where 3 >= (query)
```

to

```
where (query) <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the inner select on its own

```
select count(distinct salary) from worker w2 where w1.salary <= w2.salary
```

which will return a number of records (meeting its where clause condition)

The outer query is now simply 'select ... where 3 >= (result of inner query)'